# How to get the n next values of a generator into a list

Tags: python, list, generator

I have made a generator to read a file word by word and it works nicely.

```
def word_reader(file):
    for line in open(file):
        for p in line.split():
            yield p

reader = word_reader('txtfile')
next(reader)
```

What is the easiest way of getting the n next values into a list?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5234090/1709587; I haven't flagged because I need to look carefully and decide which one to close. Probably close this one.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
list(itertools.islice(it, n))
```

Comment: An easy way to think about the arguments of `islice()` is that they exactly mirror the arguments of `range()`:  `islice([start,] stop[, step])` (with the limitation that step > 0)

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin: Although there is one quirk, in that `stop` can be explicitly `None`, which means the `islice` object itself will never stop iterating unless the underlying iterable stops. In that use case, you're trying to skip elements (initial elements for `start`, `step-1` elements between yields for `step > 1`), not truncate the input once you've gotten far enough. `range` doesn't accept `None` as a `stop` value (`itertools.count` fills that niche), so the abstraction using `range` is just a titch leaky.

Answer (score 19):

TL;DR: Use `itertools.islice`.

Originally I wrote another answer, that turned out to be a **bad idea**:

> ```
> [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
> ```

This crashes when `it` yields less than `n` values, and this behaviour depends on subtle issues, so people reading such code are unlikely to understand it's precise semantics.

#### What happens if `next(it)` was exhausted and raises `StopIteration`?

(i.e. when `it` had less than `n` values to yield)

When I wrote the above line a couple years ago, I probably thought a `StopIteration` will have the clever side effect of cleanly terminating the list comprehension.  But no, the whole comprehension will crash passing the `StopIteration` upwards.  (It'd exit cleanly only if the exception originated from the `range(n)` iterator.)

Which is probably not the behavior you want.

But it gets worse.  The following is supposed to be equivalent to the list comprehension (especially on Python 3):

```
list(next(it) for _ in range(n))
```

It isn't.  The inner part is shorthand for a generator function; `list()` knows it's done when it raises `StopIteration` *anywhere*.
=> This version copes safely when there aren't `n` values and returns a shorter list.  (Like `itertools.islice()`.)

[Executions on: [2.7](https://ideone.com/KJeZii), [3.4](https://ideone.com/KJeZii)]

But that's too going to change!  The fact a generator silently exits when any code inside it raises `StopIteration` is a known wart, addressed by [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/).  From Python 3.7 (or 3.5 with a future import) that's going to cause a `RuntimeError` instead of cleanly finishing the generator.  I.e. it'll become similar to the list comprehension's behaviour.
(Tested on a recent HEAD build)

Comment: Yes, also nice. I think the `islice` solution is a bit nicer, so I will accept that one.

Comment: Of course this answer is much nicer, because it is simpler, needs no extra module to import, has less parentheses... Maybe in Python 4 slicing returns generators by default (compare to map in Py3). I'd only change `i` to `_`, to not have "unused variable" warnings in some IDEs ;). BTW, in Haskell it's called `take N`, which is a perfect function.

Comment: Except if n is larger then the generator's length you will get a StopIteration and a none defined variable.

Comment: @xApple oops, you're right!  And it's confusingly different if written as list(genartor expr.).  Edited to explain this, upvoted `islice`.

Comment: If you don't mind spurious values, you can use the default arg of the `next` function and call, for example `[next(it, None) for _ in range(n)]`

Answer (score 4):

```
for i, word in zip(range(n), word_reader(file)):
    ...
```

Comment: This is bad, because it consumes and extra element from the generator. Beni's answer doesn't do that.

Comment: This one-off is avoided if you do `for i, word in zip(xrange(n), word_reader(file)):`.  Though I'd prefer a reliable bug over such fragile order-dependent "fix" :-)

Comment: Still this seems the simplest using only primitives.

Answer (score 4):

To get the first n values of a generator, you can use [more_itertools.take](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.take).

If you plan to iterate over the words in chunks (eg. 100 at a time), you can use more_itertools.chunked (https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):

```
import more_itertools
for words in more_itertools.chunked(reader, n=100):
    # process 100 words
```

Comment: I looked at the source code of `take` in more_itertools and to me it seems that the definition of `take` is just `list(islice(iterable, n))`.  This, if you don't want to install a separate package for this, there should be no disadvantage to using the `islice` solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use [cytoolz.take](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.take).

```
>>> from cytoolz import take
>>> list(take(2, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]))
[10, 20]
```