# How to take the first N items from a generator or list?

Tags: python, list, generator

With [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) I would

```
var top5 = array.Take(5);
```

How to do this with Python?

Comment: @ThorSummoner I guess OP assumed there's a unified way to do it in Python.

Comment: Just to note: I flipped the duplicate closure of this question w/r/t [Fetch first 10 results from a list in Python](/q/10897339/4518341) because this question is sort of asking two things, but that question is only asking one thing, so I hope it's easier to follow, especially for beginners.

Comment: Yeah, Checkout the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and more technically, [Python's `collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) -- which unfortunately require a little interpretation, but we can see that `Generator`s have `close, __iter__, __next__` methods, and Lists (which are likely most similar to `MutableSequence`s) have one overlapping method: `__iter__`. therefore `iter([0, 1])` and `def fib():...` `iter(fib())` will provide a common interface to either a generator or list, in the form of a generator, see: `islice`

Answer (score 728, accepted):

## Slicing a list

```
top5 = array[:5]
```

- To slice a list, there's a simple syntax: `array[start:stop:step]`
- You can omit any parameter. These are all valid: `array[start:]`, `array[:stop]`, `array[::step]`

## Slicing a generator

```py
import itertools
top5 = itertools.islice(my_list, 5) # grab the first five elements
```

- You can't slice a generator directly in Python. [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) will wrap an object in a new slicing generator using the syntax `itertools.islice(generator, start, stop, step)`
- Remember, slicing a generator will exhaust it partially. If you want to keep the entire generator intact, perhaps turn it into a tuple or list first, like: `result = tuple(generator)`

Comment: Also note that `itertools.islice` will return a generator.

Comment: "If you want to keep the entire generator intact, perhaps turn it into a tuple or list first" -> won't that exhaust the generator fully, in the process of building up the tuple / list?

Comment: @lucid_dreamer yes, but then you have a new data structure (tuple/list) that you can iterate over as much as you like

Comment: To create copies of the generator before exhausting it, you can also use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), e.g.: `generator, another_copy = itertools.tee(generator)`

Comment: Note: which slice gets which elements is determined by the order in which the slices are exhausted not in which they are created. `import itertools as it;r=(i for i in range(10));s1=itt.islice(r, 5);s2=itt.islice(r, 5);l2=list(s2);l1=list(s1)` ends with `l1==[5,6,7,8,9]` and `l2==[0,1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 153):

```
import itertools

top5 = itertools.islice(array, 5)
```

Comment: This also has the nice property of returning the entire array when you have None in place of 5.

Comment: and if you want to take the five that follows each time you can use: iter(array) instead of array.

Comment: note that if your generator exhausts this will not make an error, you will get a many elements as the generator had left, less than your request size.

Comment: This is the approach used in the following: [Itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)
`def take(n, iterable): return list(islice(iterable, n))`

Answer (score 67):

[@Shaikovsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26186228/4298200) is excellent, but I wanted to clarify a couple of points.

`[next(generator) for _ in range(n)]`

This is the most simple approach, but throws `StopIteration` if the generator is prematurely exhausted.

---

On the other hand, the following approaches return **up to** `n` items which is preferable in many circumstances:

List:
`[x for _, x in zip(range(n), records)]`

Generator:
`(x for _, x in zip(range(n), records))`

Comment: Could those few people downvoting this answer please explain why?

Comment: def take(num,iterable): return([elem for _ , elem in zip(range(num), iterable)])

Comment: Above code: Loop over an iterable which could be a generator or list and return up to n elements from iterable. In case n is greater or equal to number of items existing in iterable then return all elements in iterable.

Comment: For a `list` `x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `x[:20]` also return only the 6 elements in `x`. Guess `x[:N]` return first N elements of `x`, if `N > len(x)`, it will return `x`. python 3.6.

Comment: This is the most efficient. Because this doesn't process the full list.

Comment: `[next(generator, None) for _ in range(n)]`
if you don't mind the `None`

Answer (score 52):

In my taste, it's also very concise to combine `zip()` with `xrange(n)` (or `range(n)` in Python3), which works nice on generators as well and seems to be more flexible for changes in general.

```
# Option #1: taking the first n elements as a list
[x for _, x in zip(xrange(n), generator)]

# Option #2, using 'next()' and taking care for 'StopIteration'
[next(generator) for _ in xrange(n)]

# Option #3: taking the first n elements as a new generator
(x for _, x in zip(xrange(n), generator))

# Option #4: yielding them by simply preparing a function
# (but take care for 'StopIteration')
def top_n(n, generator):
    for _ in xrange(n):
        yield next(generator)
```

Answer (score 22):

The answer for how to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152376/how-to-get-the-n-next-values-of-a-generator-in-a-list-python)

```
>>> generator = (i for i in xrange(10))
>>> list(next(generator) for _ in range(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(next(generator) for _ in range(4))
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(next(generator) for _ in range(4))
[8, 9]
```

Notice that the last call asks for the next 4 when only 2 are remaining.  The use of the `list()` instead of `[]` is what gets the comprehension to terminate on the `StopIteration` exception that is thrown by `next()`.

Comment: [Caveats on some python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152713/5353461)

Comment: to clarify Tom's comment: in python 3.7 you'll get a `RuntimeError` (the link is definitely worth the read though!)

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean the *first* N items, or the N *largest* items?

If you want the first:

```
top5 = sequence[:5]
```

This also works for the largest N items, assuming that your sequence is sorted in descending order. (Your LINQ example seems to assume this as well.)

If you want the largest, and it isn't sorted, the most obvious solution is to sort it first:

```
l = list(sequence)
l.sort(reverse=True)
top5 = l[:5]
```

For a more performant solution, use a min-heap (thanks Thijs):

```
import heapq
top5 = heapq.nlargest(5, sequence)
```

Comment: wouldn't the smaller come first?

Comment: use *sequence* instead of *iterable*. Some *iterables* do not support indexing. Every *sequence* is an *iterable*, but some *iterables* are not sequences.

Comment: Note `nlargest` takes any iterable, not only sequences.

Answer (score 3):

With `itertools` you will obtain another generator object so in most of the cases you will need another step the take the first `n` elements. There are at least two simpler solutions (a little bit less efficient in terms of performance but very handy) to get the elements ready to use from a `generator`:

Using list comprehension:

```
first_n_elements = [generator.next() for i in range(n)]
```

Otherwise:

```
first_n_elements = list(generator)[:n]
```

Where `n` is the number of elements you want to take (e.g. n=5 for the first five elements).

Answer (score -8):

This should work

```
top5 = array[:5]
```

Comment: @JoshWolff I didn't downvote this answer, but it's likely because this approach will not work with generators, unless they define `__getitem__()`. Try running `itertools.count()[:5]` or `(x for x in range(10))[:5]`, for instance, and see the error messages. The answer is, however, idiomatic for lists.