# enumerating numbers in strings

Tags: python, string, replace, enumeration

This seems like a problem that would have a fairly straight-forward answer; sadly, I am not that fluent in Python as I'm still learning, and I have not been able to find anything helpful on Google.

My goal is to enumerate the numbers in a string based on how much padding that number already has. I think the best way to describe it is with an example:

- `0-file` will be enumerated from `0-file` to `9-file`
- but `000-file` will be enumerated from `000-file` to `999-file`.

ultimately i want to be able to do this for `[number][a-z]`, `[a-z][number]`, and `[a-z][number].*` (so something like `file10name.so` wouldn't match), however I think I can figure that part out myself with regex later on.

So, the question boils down to this:

- how do I get the length of 'padding' in the file?
- how do I identify where in the string this number is, so I can replace it?
- how do I add the padding when I'm iterating (I'm assuming `zfill`, but I'm interested if there's a better method).

quick edit: yes, the 'psudo regex' is just that. it was to get the concept conveyed, hence why it wouldn't match things like "-". padding would always be a number, not necessarily 0, but thats alright. both answers this received so far are perfect. i can adapt them to my needs. Im already handeling full paths, but its great to have that there for other people who see this in the future. thanks everyone :)

Comment: Would the "padding" letter always be `'a'`? Does the "padding" always have to be at the start of the filename? What if there are other `'a'`s or `'0'`s in the filename "template"? Does your "padding" have to be e.g. `'0'`, or could you use special characters like the `'{}'` used in string formatting?

Comment: Other relevant questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20926491/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23709247/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why did you remove the `.*` in one of the OP regex examples?

Comment: @Bakuriu none of the other examples included the file extension, so I assumed it could be ignored for most purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should figure out a correct specification for the files you're trying to match before coding it up. The pseudo-regexps you gave for the filenames you are trying to match ("`[number][a-z]` or `[a-z][number]`") don't even include the examples you gave, such as `0-file`.

## Simple version

However, taking your stated specification at face value, assuming you wish to include uppercase Latin letters as well, here's a simple function that will match `[number][a-z]` or `[a-z][number]`, and return the appropriate prefix, suffix, and number of numeric digits.

```
import re

def find_number_in_filename(fn):
    m = re.match(r"(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)$", fn)
    if m:
        prefix, suffix, num_length = "", m.group(2), len(m.group(1))
        return prefix, suffix, num_length

    m = re.match(r"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)$", fn)
    if m:
        prefix, suffix, num_length = m.group(1), "", len(m.group(2))
        return prefix, suffix, num_length

    return fn, "", 0

example_fn = ("000foo", "bar14", "baz0", "file10name")
for fn in example_fn:
    prefix, suffix, num_length = find_number_in_filename(fn)
    if num_length == 0:
        print "%s: does not match" % fn
    else:
        print "%s -> %s[%d-digits]%s" % (fn, prefix, num_length, suffix)

        all_numbered_versions = [("%s%0"+str(num_length)+"d%s") % (prefix, ii, suffix) for ii in range(0,10**num_length)]
        print "\t", all_numbered_versions[0], "through", all_numbered_versions[-1]
```

The output will be:

```
000foo -> [3-digits]foo
    000foo through 999foo
bar14 -> bar[2-digits]
    bar00 through bar99
baz0 -> baz[1-digits]
    baz0 through baz9
file10name: does not match
```

Notice that I'm using a standard `printf`-style string format to convert numbers to 0-padded strings, e.g. `%03d` for 3-digit numbers with 0-padding. Using the newer [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) may be preferable for future-proofing.

## Handle full paths and extensions gracefully

If your input includes full paths and filenames with extensions (e.g. `/home/someone/project/foo000.txt`) and you want to match based on the last piece of the path only, then use `os.path.split` and `.splitext` to do the trick.

**UPDATE:** fixed missing path separator

```
import re
import os.path

def find_number_in_filename(path):
    # remove the path and the extension
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    head = os.path.join(head, "") # include / or \ on the end of head if it's missing
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(tail)

    m = re.match(r"(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)$", fn)
    if m:
        prefix, suffix, num_length = head, m.group(2)+ext, len(m.group(1))
        return prefix, suffix, num_length

    m = re.match(r"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)$", fn)
    if m:
        prefix, suffix, num_length = head+m.group(1), ext, len(m.group(2))
        return prefix, suffix, num_length

    return path, "", 0

example_paths = ("/tmp/bar14.so", "/home/someone/0000baz.txt", "/home/someone/baz00bar.zip")
for path in example_paths:
    prefix, suffix, num_length = find_number_in_filename(path)
    if num_length == 0:
        print "%s: does not match" % path
    else:
        print "%s -> %s[%d-digits]%s" % (path, prefix, num_length, suffix)

        all_numbered_versions = [("%s%0"+str(num_length)+"d%s") % (prefix, ii, suffix) for ii in range(0,10**num_length)]
        print "\t", all_numbered_versions[0], "through", all_numbered_versions[-1]
```

Comment: @user3669443, good catch on the missing path separator (`/` or `\\`) in the second version. My bad. Your suggested edit wasn't a correct solution for this, since it added the path separator in the wrong location in some cases. I made a subsequent edit that should get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator implementation, based on `str.lstrip` and `str.format`. It parses the input into a standard string template (e.g. `'{0:02d}-file'`), then loops over the appropriate values and uses that template to create the output:

```
def process(s):
    zeros = len(s) - len(s.lstrip('0'))
    template = "{{0:0{0}d}}{1}".format(zeros, s.lstrip('0')) 
    for i in range(10**zeros):
        yield template.format(i)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(process('00-file'))
['00-file', '01-file', '02-file', ..., '98-file', '99-file']
```

It has the following limitations:

- Only supports `'0'` padding; and
- Only supports leading padding;

but you can take this and adapt it to your own purposes.