# Convert a Haskell code to Python or pseudocode

Tags: python, haskell

I am working on [an algorithm](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf). But I am not very clear on the haskell code provide by the author, so I need you guys' help.
The codes can split into two parts, I think.

```hs
> type LFT = (Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer)
>
> extr :: LFT -> Integer -> Rational
> extr (q,r,s,t) x = ((fromInteger q) * x + (fromInteger r)) / ((fromInteger s) * x + (fromInteger t))
>
> unit :: LFT
> unit = (1,0,0,1)
>
> comp :: LFT -> LFT -> LFT
> comp (q,r,s,t) (u,v,w,x) = (q*u+r*w,q*v+r*x,s*u+t*w,s*v+t*x)
```

Here, very clearly, a type called LFT (may be a tuple in Python) and three function called `extr unit comp` be defined.However, the next part puzzled me a lot:

```hs
> pi = stream next safe prod cons init lfts where
>   init = unit
>   lfts = [(k, 4*k+2, 0, 2*k+1) | k<-[1..]]
>   next z = floor (extr z 3)
>   safe z n = (n == floor (extr z 4))
>   prod z n = comp (10, -10*n, 0, 1) z
>   cons z z’ = comp z z’
```

I believe `lfts` is a generator but I am failed to understand how the loop performed in this code and I do not know much about the Haskell. Can you help me convert this one to Python or a pseudocode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the `lfts` is an infinite list. You can write very similar code using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```py
from itertools import count

# count(1) is "equivalent2 to [1..]
lfts = ((k, 4*k+2, 0, 2*k+1) for k in count(1))
```

Now the important thing of the code is the call to `stream` which is a function that "performs the loop". That function is defined in the article as:

```hs
> stream :: (b->c) -> (b->c->Bool) -> (b->c->b) -> (b->a->b) ->
>           b -> [a] -> [c]
> stream next safe prod cons z (x:xs)
>   = if   safe z y
>     then y : stream next safe prod cons (prod z y) (x:xs)
>     else stream next safe prod cons (cons z x) xs
>       where y = next z
```

The idea of `stream` is that:

- The last argument (`x:xs`) is an (infinite) input list (of type `[a]`)
- The one-to-last argument (`z`) is some form of *state* (of type `b`)
- The other four arguments are functions that manipulate inputs and state:

  - The `next` function takes a state and produces an output (`y`).
  - The `safe` function checks whether `y` should be added in the output or not
  - The `prod` function produces the new state
  - The `cons` function is called when the `y` value is *not* added to the output and is used to produce the new state from the input value `x`.

You can reproduce such a function as:

```py
import itertools as it

def stream(nxt, safe, prod, cons, state, inputs):
    x = next(inputs)   # obtain x
    # xs = inputs
    y = nxt(state)
    if safe(state, y):
        yield y
        inputs = it.chain([x], inputs)   # put x back in the input
        yield from stream(nxt, safe, prod, cons, prod(state, y), inputs)
    else:
        yield from stream(nxt, safe, prod, cons, cons(state, x), inputs)
```

So basically what this does is that it yields some values starting from a certain state. When it reaches a certain condition it consume an input value to produce a new state and yield more values, when it stops again it will use an other input value to produce a new state again etc. Ad infinitum.

Note that the above implementation will have really bad performance. It's better to avoid recursion in python so I'd use:

```py
def stream(nxt, safe, prod, cons, state, inputs):
    while True:
        x = next(inputs)   # obtain x
        # xs = inputs
        y = nxt(state)
        if safe(state, y):
            yield y
            inputs = it.chain([x], inputs)   # put x back in the input
            state = prod(state, y)
        else:
            state = cons(state, x)
```

Answer (score 3):

`lfts` is indeed a (lazy) generator which is more or less equivalent to:

```
def lfts () :
    k = 1
    while True :
        yield (k,4*k+2,0,2*k+1)
        k += 1
```

This is because `[1..]` is an infinite list of incrementing integers starting from `1`. Now `k <- [1..]` means that `k` each time picks the next value in the list, and you `yield` the thing at the left of the list comprehension.

It is thus a generator that will generate an *infinite* list, therefore you cannot simply call `list()` or `len()` onto it.

---

You can also use [`count`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) from `itertools` to produce a oneliner:

```
((k,4*k+2,0,2*k+1) for k in itertools.count(1))
```

You can then take for instance the first five elements using [`itertools.islice`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234170/67579):

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(((k,4*k+2,0,2*k+1) for k in itertools.count(1)), 0, 5))
[(1, 6, 0, 3), (2, 10, 0, 5), (3, 14, 0, 7), (4, 18, 0, 9), (5, 22, 0, 11)]
```

Since the generator can generate elements until the end of times, you can easily take an arbitrary amount of elements (above five, but twenty is evidently an option as well).

Comment: That is very clear, but I can not understand how the **iteration** performed in this code. Could you make an explain?

Comment: @DavidPage: In python you can use the `yield` keyword to describe a generator. Python sees this as a *continuation*: if you ask for the first element it will process until it hits the first `yield` statement, and then suspend execution of the method. If you later ask the next element, it will again process and suspend after it has yielded the second element, and so on.