# Get first N items of list, ok if list is shorter

Tags: python

Print first N items of a list/generator

This works for plain lists. It prints the first 3 items of the list

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4]
print(l[:min(3, len(l))])
```

I want this work for lists with less then three items, too. If there is only one item in the list, then print one item.

AFAIK len(l) only works for lists. How to implement this for generators?

Comment: This will probably help with the generator question: [How to take the first N items from a generator or list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list-in-python)

Comment: *"I want this work for lists with less then three items, too"* - ...it does?

Answer (score 12):

You can just use `l[:3]`, no need for anything else:

```
In [11]: l = [1, 2, 3 ,4]

In [12]: print(l[:3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

This will work exactly the same for generators:

```
In [19]: def firstn(n):
    ...:     num = 0
    ...:     while num < n:
    ...:         yield num
    ...:         num += 1
    ...:

In [20]: list(firstn(5))[:3]
Out[20]: [0, 1, 2]
```

It also works for containers which have fewer than `n` elements:

```
n = 20
lyst = [1, 2]
print(lyst[:20])  # prints [1, 2]
```

Comment: Question is for generator and not for List.

Comment: @Ajeet, just added the example for generators

Comment: Generators are potentially infinitely long. It's also hugely inefficient to exhaust them *then* slice.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use `islice` from `itertools`. eg. `max(islice(iter(range(m)), n))` works for all possible positive integer value pairs of `m` and `n`.

Comment: @Dunes, I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Is it regarding the code of the generator? If so - this is only an example of the `[:3]` part on generators.

Comment: What I'm saying is that `islice` provides the functionality provided by `firstn` and more. It mimics slicing functionality for generators.

Comment: Got it. If the user only want to get the first N items I don't think the using the `itertools.islice` is required :) thats all

Comment: But it is, for exactly the reasons I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

For lists you can use

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l[:3])
```

This won't fail also for shorter lists. If you want to use generators, I think the best way is converting the generator to a list and doing the same

```
a = (i for i in range(0, 4))  # example of generator
print(list(a)[:3])
```

Also won't fail for shorter generators

If you want to get a generator after the slice, use `itertools`

```
import itertools
print(itertools.islice(generated_list, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a generator to produce min(N,len(generator)).

Apply `slice` to generator directly. No need instantiate the list.
This will produce min(N,len(generator)) lengthed generator.

e.g.

```
>>> l = range(5)
>>> l[:10]
range(0, 5)
>>>
```

Comment: The range object is a special case, this won't work on arbitrary generators.