# Get a generator to return first n combinations

Tags: python-2.7, generator, combinations, python-itertools

I am using `itertools.combinations` to get all possible tuples of two numbers / combinations ( [(1,2), (1,3) ...] ) of 1M numbers i.e. from [1,2,3,4, ..... , 1000000]. I can generate all combinations but is there a way to get a generator which will only return requested combinations. e.g. I want 1st 10K combinations, I can get this like

```
combinations = itertools.combinations(numbers, 2)
chunk = list(combinations)[:10000]
```

but this code will load all combinations into the memory which is a very bad idea. I want a generator that will return 1st 10K combinations without loading all combinations into memory. like this

```
combinations = itertools.combinations(numbers, 2)
chunk1_generator = some_magic(combinations, 0, 9999)
```

In a similar way,

```
chunk2_generator = some_magic(combinations, 10000, 19999)
```

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.islice`?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I should search with a generic generator case instead. similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5234115/5567387