# Limiting number of inputs while accepting from a space separated input

Tags: python, input

I am using `input().split()` method to input elements in a list from a space separated single line input in python. However, I am unable to find a way to limit the inputs. As in if user is giving more than desired inputs in single line, is there any method to check that?

I read about assert method, but couldn't implement it correctly.

```
import numpy
m,n = map(int,input().split())
a = numpy.array([input().split() for i in range(n)], int)
print(a)
```

Input:

```
3 2

1 2 3 4 5

3 4 5 6 7
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [3 4 5 6 7]]
```

I want the row should contain 3 elements per row and rest of the entries should be avoided/discarded without any errors. Please help.
Expected Output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [3 4 5]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is basically there, I'd just use [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234170/1358308) to limit the maximum number of elements, e.g. `lst[:3]` evaluates to a list of at most 3 elements.

in your example, this would be:

```
import numpy
m,n = map(int,input().split())
a = numpy.array([input().split()[:m] for i in range(n)], int)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_input():
        user_input = input("Input: ")

        split_input = user_input.split()

        if len(split_input) > 3:
                raise Exception("Too much input")

        return split_input
```

Instead of rasing an exception, you can have some output or another input attemp etc.

Comment: Thanks Nixon, but I wanted it to be handled internally and Sam's list slicing idea works well.