# Large list generation memory managment

Tags: python, memory

```
import itertools
Num = 11

base = list(range(1,Num+1))

Permutations = list(itertools.permutations(base))
```

I'm getting a memory error trying to run this. In reality I only need to generate the 1st (Num-1)! permutations but I'm not sure how to (so if Num = 7 i would need to generate the first 6! = 720 permutations). But I would ideally like to be able to generate permutations for significantly higher values of Num so any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range()` and `permutation()` both return generators that generate items on demand. You don't need to call `list()` and turn them into lists. Just iterate over them directly and access the items one by one.

```
num = 11
base = range(1, num+1)
permutations = itertools.permutations(base)

for permutation in permutations:
    # Do something with `permutation`.
```

(Note that a generator can only be used once. If you want to iterate over the permutations more than once you'll need to call `itertools.permutations()` multiple times.)

To [stop after *n* items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list-in-python) use `itertools.islice()`:

```
for permutation in itertools.islice(permutations, n):
    # Do something with `permutation`.
```

You can skip items at the beginning, too. This would skip the first five permutations:

```
for permutation in itertools.islice(permutations, 5, n):
    # Do something with `permutation`.
```

If you want to count the permutations you can add `enumerate()`, which attaches an index to every entry:

```
for i, permutation in enumerate(itertools.islice(permutations, n)):
    # Skip the fifth permutation.
    if i == 4:
        continue

    # Do something with `permutation`.
```

By the way, please use lowercase for variable names. Only class names should be capitalized.