# How to select dictionary by using certain keys in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this kind of `JSON data` and have around `100` questions. How can I filter the question only up to `40`?

This is the sample of data:

```
data=[{"id": "AA11",
"resp": [
    {"answer": "A","number": 1},
    {"answer": "A","number": 2},
    {"answer": "B","number": 3},
    {"answer": "D","number": 4},
    {"answer": "E","number": 5}
]},
{"id": "AA22",
"resp": [
    {"answer": "A","number": 1},
    {"answer": "A","number": 2},
    {"answer": "B","number": 3},
    {"answer": "D","number": 4},
    {"answer": "E","number": 5}
]},
{"id": "AA33",
"resp": [
    {"answer": "A","number": 1},
    {"answer": "A","number": 2},
    {"answer": "B","number": 3},
    {"answer": "D","number": 4},
    {"answer": "E","number": 5}
]}]
```

Can I extract the data only up to number 3 as example in this case?

Output:

```
data=[{"id": "AA11",
"resp": [
    {"answer": "A","number": 1},
    {"answer": "A","number": 2},
    {"answer": "B","number": 3}
]},
{"id": "AA22",
"resp": [
    {"answer": "A","number": 1},
    {"answer": "A","number": 2},
    {"answer": "B","number": 3}
]},
{"id": "AA33",
"resp": [
    {"answer": "A","number": 1},
    {"answer": "A","number": 2},
    {"answer": "B","number": 3}
]}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take the first N items from a generator or list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in data:
    item['resp'] = item['resp'][:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic way would be a comprehension:

```
filtered = [{'id': d['id'], 'resp': [x for x in d['resp'] if x['number'] <= 3]}
            for d in data]
```

It gives as expected:

```
[{'id': 'AA11',
  'resp': [{'answer': 'A', 'number': 1},
           {'answer': 'A', 'number': 2},
           {'answer': 'B', 'number': 3}]},
 {'id': 'AA22',
  'resp': [{'answer': 'A', 'number': 1},
           {'answer': 'A', 'number': 2},
           {'answer': 'B', 'number': 3}]},
 {'id': 'AA33',
  'resp': [{'answer': 'A', 'number': 1},
           {'answer': 'A', 'number': 2},
           {'answer': 'B', 'number': 3}]}]
```

Comment: "...Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts..." -The Zen of Python

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
new_data = data[0:40]
for item in new_data:
    item['resp'] = item['resp'][0:3]
```

This solution will create a new dictionary with expected values.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering up to a specific element should can be done like this

```
def filter(question,num):
    temp = {}
    for key in question:
        temp[key] = question[key]
    temp['resp'] = question['resp'][:num]
    return temp

def filter_list(questions,num):
    temp = []
    for question in questions:
        temp.append(filter(question,num))
    return temp

data = [{}...]
filtered_data = filter_list(data)
```

You'll notice that `filter` creates a copy of `question` and only changes the copy. It can be useful to change data structures, but it's good practice to treat data structures as immutable where possible.

As a bonus, you won't lose any of the original data this way