# how to fetch 49 index value from a 100 element list without indexing?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, printing

I have a 100 element list with strings in it i want to fetch 49 element from the list without using indexing how can I do that .

I want the answer in a form of code which will fetch the 49 element without using indexing that is the only requirement of that program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: So, you cannot do my_list[48]? Why?

Comment: Sorry, @Vishal, this sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: possible duplicate ...Does this answer your question? [How to take the first N items from a generator or list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list)