# Odoo record limit

Tags: python, odoo

How can I show specific number of records from api. That means if the model have 100 records i need to show only 50 records. How can I do that in api.here the api i am showing data from res.partner in this api. how can I show only specific number of records. please help me.

here is my code:

```
@http.route('/api/get-restaurant-list', type='json', methods=['POST', 'GET'], auth='public')
    def get_restaurant_list(self, **kwargs):
        restaurants = request.env['res.partner']
        filter_domain = [('usertype', '=', 'restaurant')]
        if 'filter_by' in kwargs:
            filters = kwargs.get('filter_by')
            for k in filters:
                if k == 'available_food' or k == 'country_name' or k == 'state_name' or k == 'district_name':
                    if k == 'available_food':
                        filter_domain.append((k + '.name', 'in', filters.get(k)))
                    if k == 'country_name':
                        country_name = filters[k]
                        filter_domain.append(('country_id.name', '=', country_name))
                    if k == 'state_name':
                        state_name = filters[k]
                        filter_domain.append(('state_id.name', '=', state_name))
                    if k == 'district_name':
                        district_name = filters[k]
                        filter_domain.append(('district_id.name', '=', district_name))
                else:
                    filter_domain.append((k, '=', kwargs.get('filter_by').get(k)))
        if 'search' in kwargs:
            filter_domain.append(('name', 'ilike', kwargs.get('search')))
        restaurants = restaurants.sudo().search(filter_domain)
        restaurant_list = []
        for r in restaurants:
            val = {
                "id": r.id,
                "name": r.name,
                "email": r.email,
                "mobile": r.mobile,
                "street": r.street,
                "street2": r.street2,
                "zip": r.zip,
                "city": r.city,
                "state_id": r.state_id.id,
                "state_name": r.state_id.name,
                "country_id": r.country_id.id,
                "country_name": r.country_id.name,
                "district_id": r.district_id.id,
                "district_name": r.district_id.name,
                "opening_time": r.time,
                # "opening_time": ('%.2f' % float(r.time)).replace('.', ':') if float(r.time) == int(
                #     float(r.time)) else ':'.join([str(r.time).split('.')[0], str(
                #     int((int('{:<02}'.format(str(r.time).split('.')[1])) * 60) / 100))]),
                # "food_type_preferences": [{"id": f.id, "name": f.name} for f in r.food_type_preference_ids],
                "available_food": [a.name for a in r.available_food],
                "food_menus": [
                    {"id": fm.id, "name": fm.name, "price": fm.price, "description": fm.description}
                    for fm in r.menu_ids],
                "location": {
                    "lat": r.partner_latitude,
                    "long": r.partner_longitude
                },
                "rating_avg": r.get_avg_rating(),
                # "image": r.image_128,
                "image": _generate_image_path(model=r._name, id=r.id,
                                                  field='image_1920')
            }
            restaurant_list.append(val)
        data = {"success": True, "data": restaurant_list}
        return data
```

Comment: You mean you already got 100 records in `restaurant_list`, and you want to reduce it to 50 records? If so, what is the criteria for that?

Comment: I mean If I have 20 records in restaurant_list. i need to show a specific number of records. that means i want to show first or last 10 records.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list

Comment: here how can i use this?

Comment: Look into the `search` method. You could add `limit` and `order` to your request json payload and use it for the search to manipulate the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` argument in `search` function

`self.env['my.model'].search(domain=[], limit=10, offset=5, order='create_date asc')`