# How do I put a break in a single-line for loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot and returning a list of item. Unfortunately, if the list exceeds 25 items, it throws an error. I want break the loop after 25 loops. Below is a sample of code provided in the discord.py documentation; the for loop is a single line and does not work if I try to modify it:

```
async def fruit_autocomplete(
interaction: discord.Interaction,
current: str,
) -> List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    fruits = ['Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Melon', 'Cherry']
    return [
        app_commands.Choice(name=fruit, value=fruit)
        for fruit in fruits if current.lower() in fruit.lower()
    ]
```

Comment: don't use list comprehension, use regular loop. Even now, it's not single line anyway

Comment: @buran it can be. But yes, the qestion and example is misleading if together taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.islice`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234170/10237506) to take first `N` results from a generator `(...)`:

```
async def fruit_autocomplete(
interaction: discord.Interaction,
current: str,
) -> Iterable[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    fruits = ['Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Melon', 'Cherry']
    return itertools.islice(
        (app_commands.Choice(name=fruit, value=fruit)
        for fruit in fruits if current.lower() in fruit.lower())
    , 25)
```

If desiring a `List` as result, wrap above return with `list(...)`.

---

With just a `list`, slice with `[:N]`:

```
async def fruit_autocomplete(
interaction: discord.Interaction,
current: str,
) -> List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    fruits = ['Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Melon', 'Cherry']
    current = current.lower()
    return [app_commands.Choice(name=f, value=f)
            for f in fruits if current in f.lower()][:25]
```

Comment: `itertools.islice` will return generator, not list and in both cases they will need to create the full list first and then convert to generator or slice it

Comment: @buran yes, good point. I updated answer as I realize this too.

Comment: also, if they will return generator, why use isllce, just return generator expression/generator, instead of list

Comment: right, but from what I gather they only want the first 25 results from the generator expression

Comment: @buran You're wrong ("in both cases they will need to create the full list first"). When using `islice(generator, 25)`, only 25 `app_commands.Choice` objects will be created. When using a list comprehension, potentially more would be created (if `fruits` was larger). This distinction is important when it's costly to fetch these items.

Comment: @NiccoloM., I agree - ma bad, I overlooked that there is generator inside the islice. However, you are wrong too :-) - they will create generator and no app_commands.Choice objects will be created until they consume the generator at later stage.