# TypeError on Generator object with Linux Mint. Code works fine in Win11

Tags: python, generator

I have code for running a google search from terminal.
The weird thing is it works just fine in my win11, but when I launch it in Linux Mint I get a TypeError.

The code creates an error in line 13

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'generator' object is not subscriptable
    for i in result[:num_results]:
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Any ideas why this is occuring and how to fix it?

Code below:

```
from googlesearch import search
import webbrowser, sys
import time

searching_for = input(("Input search words: "))

num_results = int(input("How many results : ") or "3")

result = search(searching_for)

for i in result[:num_results]:
    webbrowser.open(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take the first N items from a generator or list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list)

Comment: BTW: I bet it fails the same on any OS if you use the same version of the components involved. Many APIs, especially when dealing with paginated responses of HTTP APIs, are moving towards generators and away from lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search` returns a generator.

Use:

`for i in list(result)[:num_results]:`

Comment: This is the wrongest you can do to a Generator. It will read every element from the Generator (millions of search results possibly), then read the first `n` and discard the rest again. Lots of useless things being done unnecessarily.