# Get multiple individual values from generator in Python

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-itertools

**How do i take multiple arbitrary values from different index positions in an iterator?**

[How to get the n next values of a generator in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4152376/596361) and [Get the nth item of a generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2300756/596361) describe the use of [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for taking arbitrary element or continuous subset from an iterator. But what if i want multiple arbitrary elements from different positions in the iterator, where you can't just use `islice`'s step argument?

I'm trying to solve Project Euler's [problem 40](http://projecteuler.net/problem=40). I generated a string of concatenated integers with

```
iteration = (i for i in ''.join(map(str, (i for i in xrange(1,10**6)))))
```

An now i want to get elements with indexes 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 counting from 1. I couldn't use `islice` here, because every call to `next` shifts current value to yield to the right. For example

```
next(islice(iteration, 1, 2)) + next(islice(iteration, 3, 4))
```

produces '26' instead of '24'.

**Update (25.11.12, 4:43 UTC+0)**:

Thanks for all the suggestions. My current code looks like:

```
it = (i for i in ''.join(map(str, (i for i in xrange(1,10**6)))))
ds = [int(nth(it, 10**i-10**(i-1)-1)) for i in range(7)]
return product(ds)
```

The ugly argument for `nth` is to generate a sequence of 0, 8, 89, 899, 8999 etc.

Comment: One issue with your current code is that it doesn't generate the digits lazily (change `10**6` to `10**7`, for example) -- `''.join` will consume what it's passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from [the "recipes" section of the itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). It returns the `n`th element of `iterable`, consuming it as it goes:

```
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

You can get the 1st, 10th, 100th etc elements by calling it sequentially (noting that the iterator gets consumed, and is zero-indexed):

```
first = nth(iteration, 0)
tenth = nth(iteration, 8)  # since we've already taken one
hundredth = nth(iteration, 89)  # since we've already taken ten
# etc
```

Alternatively, you could use `tee` and use `nth` with a different iterator each time. This way you don't have to worry about the fact that your single iterator is getting consumed. On the other hand you might start swallowing memory if your iterators are very long.

Answer (score 4):

(Note that there are much faster ways to solve Euler #40.)

I would work a little differently.  Instead of using `nth`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, count, islice
>>> 
>>> it = chain.from_iterable(str(i) for i in count(1))
>>> wanted = {10**i for i in range(7)}
>>> scan_region = islice(it, max(wanted)+1)
>>> digits = [int(x) for i, x in enumerate(scan_region, 1) if i in wanted]
>>> digits
[1, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1]
```

This way I don't have to do any subtractions to make sure I have the right indices.

Answer (score 1):

As well as looking at `nth` as mentioned - I would look at simplifying your generator:

```
from itertools import count

def concat():
    for i in count(1):
        for j in str(i):
            yield int(j)
```