# Is it possible to call more than one next value of an infinite python generator at once?

Tags: python, generator

Is there any way to get the next n values of a generator without looping or calling next() n times?
The thing that the generator in this case is infinite, and cannot be translated into a list.
Here is the generator function:

```
def f():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

The following loops both give the desired result, but I would like to know if there is some other method of doing this.

```
gen = f()
n = 0
while n < 10:
    print(next(gen))
    n += 1
```

or..

```
for n, i in enumerate(f()):
    if n < 10:
        print(i)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Well since the generator generates Fibonacci numbers, if you know the first 2 elements `a,b`, you could infer the third by doing `a+b`.

Comment: `itertools.islice` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks.. it is indeed what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.  One way is to use list comprehension, similar to what you already have above.  For instance:

```py
gen = f()
elements = [next(gen) for _ in range(10)]
```

Another way is to use something like the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html), for instance the `takeWhile()`- or `islice()`-function.

Also check out [How to get the n next values of a generator in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152376/how-to-get-the-n-next-values-of-a-generator-in-a-list-python).