# Python 3.10 Generator Expression Exception Handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below is from the book "Functional Python Programming, Steven F. Lott" however I can't handle the exception and run the code as expected.

How can I handle the "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration"?

Note: I tried googling and read all the results I found from stackoverflow.

Thanks.

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Tuple, Iterator, Any

def group_by_iter(n: int, items: Iterator) -> Iterator[Tuple]:
    """
    .>>> list( group_by_iter( 7, filter( lambda x: x%3==0 or x%5==0, range(1,50) ) ) )
    [(3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15), (18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30), (33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45), (48,)]
    """
    row = tuple(next(items) for i in range(n))
    while row:
        yield row
        row = tuple( next(items) for i in range(n) )

print( list( group_by_iter( 7, filter( lambda x: x%3==0 or x%5==0, range(1,50) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Exception is "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration".

Comment: This code relies on old, pre-[PEP 479](https://peps.python.org/pep-0479/) behavior of `StopIteration` propagating out of generators. It won't work on Python 3.7 or up.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This didn't work but is there any simple solution to work as expected. I tried the row = tuple ... inside try, exception but this didn't catch the last value.

Comment: @user2357112 Which is funny, considering that typing, used here, was introduced in Python 3.5.

Comment: @9769953: Sorry, got the Python version mixed up - the behavior change is behind a `__future__` import on Python 3.5. It only became the default in 3.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the n next values of a generator in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152376/how-to-get-the-n-next-values-of-a-generator-in-a-list-python)

Comment: @gre_gor: the answer I am looking is the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function can take a second argument which is the default value returned when the iterator is exhausted. You could exploit this functionality to avoid the `StopIteration` error by returning `None` by default and filtering it from the result.

Change `tuple(next(items) for _ in range(n))`
to `tuple(e for e in [next(items, None) for _ in range(n)] if e is not None)` and the final tuple will be generated cleanly.

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Tuple, Iterator, Any

def group_by_iter(n: int, items: Iterator) -> Iterator[Tuple]:
    """
    .>>> list( group_by_iter( 7, filter( lambda x: x%3==0 or x%5==0, range(1,50) ) ) )
    [(3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15), (18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30), (33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45), (48,)]
    """
    row = tuple(next(items) for _ in range(n))
    while row:
        yield row
        row = tuple(e for e in [next(items, None) for _ in range(n)] if e is not None)

print( list( group_by_iter( 7, filter( lambda x: x%3==0 or x%5==0, range(1,50) ) ) ) )
```

Output:

```
[(3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15), (18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30), (33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45), (48,)]
```